# How to Integrate third party libraries into React JS

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I had a template, that I wanted to convert to React JS components, and I successfully did that. As all of us know, that there are bunch of libraries used in  a template. What I first did is, I inserted the `.css` and `.js` libraries into the react app through the `index.html` file, in the public folder of the `create-react-app` boiler plate. It successfully used the styles and scripts from the inserted `.js` and `.css` files. But the problem occurred when I added routing to the react app.

When, I navigate to another route through a link, the component loads, but the required styles and scripts doesn't loads. I don't know what the problem is. I tried to import the scripts and styles to the parent component which is `home.js`. The styles worked properly, but the libraries used in template are :

`bootstrap.min.js`,
`eva.min.js`,
`feather.min.js`,
`jquery.min.js`,
`jquery-slim.min.js`, and 
`popper.min.js`.

On each import of the above libraries, it shows different errors. But as an example, for `jquery.min.js` it shows the following error :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In public folder add the following code in  of the index.html page.

```
 <base href="/">
```

Comment: what it has to do with the scripts and css ?

Comment: After adding routing path issues pop up that results in invalid CSS and js path for the routes except "/", By placing that tag in the head all CSS and js will be loaded from "/" path.